# ios bundle rejected due to lack of information

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to upload my ios app for testing through testflight. I uploaded into app store and they rejected it due to the lack of information. The questions they asked are

***To resolve this issue, please review the following questions and provide as much detailed information as you can. The more information you can provide upfront, the sooner we can complete your review.**

*- what is the intended functionality of your app?
- who are the intended audience*?

**Once you reply to this message in Resolution Center with the requested information, we can proceed with your review.***

I replied with proper answers. Its been two days, still it shows the same error message. Will it take more time or should I go for an appeal? What will be the solution? Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Just wait. Apple is not always quick with their reviews.

Comment: Ok..Thanks for the info bro

Comment: Last time I waited for the review for 7 days. Waiting is your only option.

Comment: @Adlorem..My confusion is I provided the answer and clicked  the send button...But still the same error meesage shows. Why it didnt changes to reviewing or somethimg? My answers are in theri timeline also

Comment: You have to wait the response.